# Black bar always appearing in Ubuntu 9.04 screenshots

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Every time that I take a screenshot using the native Take Screenshot tool it comes up something like this...

[image]

As I said in the title I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 on a Dell Inspiron 600m laptop with an external monitor as a second screen. When I take the screenshot on the laptop monitor it comes out as above, but when I take it on the external monitor the black bar only extends across 3/5 of the image. What could possibly be causing this annoyance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Google search tells me: a bug.

https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/gnome-utils/+bug/379382
http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587101

The solution? None at the moment.

**Workaround?** Align the top edge of your screens instead.